# Read and write EXIF data with Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, exif

I'd like to find a way to read AND write [exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data of an image with Silverlight.

I couldn't find any sample code or library doing this, so I don't know if it's even possible?

Thanks

**Update** : I need to write (edit or add if necessary) exif data and more precisely the "Software" tag.

Comment: [What is the best EXIF library for .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017/what-is-the-best-exif-library-for-net) isn't specifically about Silverlight, but it should provide a starting point.

Comment: @Matthew Indeed, this quesiton provides a starting point but lots of libraries I found rely on the GDI+ classes located in System.Drawing.Imaging, wich is not available with Silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

At work we use this, in a WPF Application so it might help

http://renaud91.free.fr/MetaDataExtractor/

Comment: +1 : that solves the first half of my problem : reading EXIF.
But I'd like to be able to add/edit tags too!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you would read in SL: [Understanding and Reading Exif Data](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Exif_Data.aspx). As the author is using `FileInfo` for this, the concept of reading can likely be reversed for writing (TIFF - Little Endian).

Comment: Here is a blog post that describes how to use this library:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/23/working-with-pictures-in-camera-tasks-in-windows-phone-7-orientation-rotation.aspx