# Set GPS Location on picture through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gps, location, exif

Is it possible to set the GPS location of a picture through JavaScript? While using Google I found a lot of ways to display this information but non on how to set it.

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense yet. Can you clarify, maybe show an example?

Comment: Sorry about that. Basically what I want to do is set location data on the picture. If you would then place it online on Flickr it would show on a specific location on the map. Not every camera has this GPS capability though, so I would like to add this information through JavaScript. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read EXIF data to get the lat/lng of an image but you certainly can't write it using Javascript

Comment: Is that because of security reasons? If it is, is there another way of writing that data, maybe through AS3?

Comment: Yes, for security reasons there is no permission for Javascript to write to the hard drive in the client machine. I don't know if it's possible through AS3 but it should be possible with Silverlight, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517094/read-and-write-exif-data-with-silverlight

Comment: This is not longer true... `FolderHandle` provide developer with option to write data to harddisk...

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to writing a Firefox extension, you would have additional privileges, and you could figure out how to manipulate images locally.

Comment: No comment on that downvote?  The asker said Javascript; he didn't specify how it would be delivered.