# Extract image file metadata

Tags: c#, windows

I want to be able to extract an image's metadata and extended properties without opening the file.  In other words, how do I programatically access the information shown when you right-click a file in windows and select the "Details" tab?

[image: Screenshot]

What is the correct way to do this using .Net Framework 4.5 and higher?  I have found various ways of doing this, but the articles all refer to .Net Framework 2 and is, to say the least, tedious and probably outdated.  Specifically, are there any libraries which makes this easy to do?

#### EDIT

I need to be able to get the height and width dimensions for images in the following formats: png, jpg, jpeg, gif, bmp and pdf (it is safe to assume that the pdf consists of 1 page only).

Comment: Exactly what metadata are you looking for?

Comment: Specifically height and width (at the moment).  From the articles I have read, some mentions that this data is not always available for all images?  If I can find a library that can work around this easily it would be a bonus (but for performance reasons I would prefer if it tries to read exif data first).

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017/what-is-the-best-exif-library-for-net

Answer (score 3):

I was playing around to accomplish this. Below are my findings.

1. You can use System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Imaging namespace
2. The latter is imported by using statement and doing Add reference => Assemblies => Framework => System.Drawing
3. Find out what the hexadecimal values mean that are stored in `PropertyItems` `Id` value.
4. Convert them to human readable text with ASCII converter.*
5. Print to screen, or whatever.

*Please note: ASCII converter prints a bunch of strange characters (e.g., "♦ ☺ ☺ ☻ ♥ ♣ ☺ ☺ ☺ ☻  ☺ ☺ ☻ ♥ ♣         ☺ ☻ ♥ ♦  ♀  ☻ ♥ ♣") and my laptop starts beeping with some properties. You probably need other encoding for those. If anyone knows which, let me know.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Add reference => Assemblies => Framework => System.Drawing

            // Set the path to your photo file.
            var path = @"[Path to your image]";

            // Create image object
            var image = new Bitmap(path);

            // Get PropertyItems
            var propItems = image.PropertyItems;

            // Remove encoding object
            var encodings = new ASCIIEncoding();

            // Display 
            foreach (var propItem in propItems)
            {

                // The values below come from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7(v=vs.110).aspx
                // Find al values available with Console.WriteLine(propItem.Id.ToString("x"));

                if (propItem.Id.ToString("x").Equals("110")) //Equipment model
                {
                    var model = encodings.GetString(propItem.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Model:\t" + model);
                }

                if (propItem.Id.ToString("x").Equals("9003")) //ExifDTOriginal
                {
                    var datetime = encodings.GetString(propItem.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Taken:\t" + datetime);
                }


            }
            Console.Read();

        }

    }
}

    // =>
    //    Model:  FinePix S9500
    //    Taken:  2012:11:30 13:58:04
```

Hope this helps. :-)

/Edit as a comment by sasha_gud states, using the [BitmapSource class, which exposes the EXIF metadata through the Metadata property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017/what-is-the-best-exif-library-for-net#2609980) is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this personally myself as I was required to read XMP data for one of my projects.

To do this I used: http://sourceforge.net/projects/csxmptk/ which is a wrapper around the Adobe's XMP toolkit.

It's not the most performant but this was not a concern for me as I did this as a batch process when the asset was uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, something needs to open the file to read the metadata. That being said, it may not be the most efficient way but the `System.Drawing.Image` class should give you everything you need. Use `FromFile` to create the Image object. You then have `Height` and `Width` properties for the dimensions and `PropertyIdList` and `PropertyItems` to get other information that may be available.

BTW, as far as I know, height and width are available for every image format.